# How to make sure custom js file loaded last in joomla

Tags: joomla

I am trying to include a custom JS file into my joomla site. What I did is to edit the template's index.php file, and add `<script src='custom.js"></script>` right before `</head>`. But when the page is loaded, there are two other JS files loaded after my custom JS file. I thought by inserting my script loading line right before the closing head tag, my JS file should be the last one to load. What could possibly load those 2 JS files after my JS file, and how?

[image: custom js inserted in index.php right before closing head tag]

[image: Yet some other JS files loaded after custom JS]

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

you can use `addCustomTag` option this will not load the `JS` file inside your head tag but it should be last (from where you are calling there it load.)

```
$stylelink .= '<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/IEonly.css" />';
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addCustomTag($stylelink);
```

For more [details](http://www.walkswithme.net/adding-stylesheet-and-scripts-using-jdocument)

Hope it works..

Answer (score 1):

There is an option to specify execution of the script after page has loaded (defer). This is a HTML feature and addScript() exposes this in its interface. Doc: https://docs.joomla.org/JDocument/addScript

Example:

```
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addScript('js/myscript.js', 'text/javascript', true);
```